# Updating WSL with Task Scheduler

Tags: sh, scheduled-tasks, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-task-scheduler

I've been attempting to update all packages in a WSL distro by scheduling an event in Windows Task Scheduler. I'm complicating things a little by having the task also change the message of the day (motd) to display when the last updates happened.

I have a task scheduled to run this command:

`wsl --distribution Arch -u root sh /mnt/d/sam8s/Arch/update.sh`

Upon running the same thing in a Windows command prompt, things work great-- all packages update, and my motd file is changed to be current. When run from task scheduler, the command returns 0x1 and no update to the motd is made.

Here are the contents of update.sh (please forgive my bad use of regexes!):

```
pacman -Syu
cd /mnt/d/sam8s/Arch
CUR_DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")
sed -E "s/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/${CUR_DATE}/g" motd > motd.bak && mv motd.bak motd
exit
```

Which removes an old date (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) from the file and adds the new one, which is formatted the same way.

Any thoughts on why this might work from command prompt but not task scheduler?

Comment: There are many options when you create a Task Scheduler. For instance, you may define which user will be used to run the program. -- Can you give us more information about the task? How did you define the task?

Comment: Thanks for following up! Here's some general info:
 - Location: \
 - Author: <hostname\myUsername>
 - Use the following user account: <myUsername>
 - Run whether or not I'm logged on
 - Run with highest privileges

Let me know if you need other details

Comment: Sorry about that, my markdown is failing me! It's too late to delete the comment and try again or I would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer was removing the option "Run whether the user is logged in or not". I'll continue looking into why this might be the case, but simply switching over to only switching to run only when the user is logged in is enough to resolve the issue.